# Java spring parse Parse JSON with extra fields

Tags: java, spring

Can Spring JSON parser map a json to a class, if JSON has more field than the class? For POST mapping, there is a possibility of having extra fields that are not nessesary for the given implementation. Can i ignore these extra fields, or do i have to add the to the object for the json parser?

Comment: Which Framework do you use?

Comment: @Jens In the title and in the tags. "Spring".

Comment: As i know spring has no own implementation of json parser

Comment: @Jens I dug around a bit. And it seems like jackson is handling the json parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible ...refer below

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Alias {
    @JsonProperty(value="AliasType")
    private String aliasType;
}
```

I recommend following tutorial though : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just add this annotation to the class of the object you want to deserialize :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```